# React - DataGrid Does not display columns

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Mui dataGrid but it doesn't display the columns.

```
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

export default function GridLiberarDemonstrativo() {
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        field: "dataLiberacao",
        headerName: "Data da liberação",
        type: "string",
        tipo: "java.long.Long",
        grid: false,
        joinType: "JOIN",
        hide: false,
        tipoFiltro: "IGUAL",
        opcoesEnum: "",
        disableColumnMenu: true,
        sequenciaOrdenacao: 1,
      },
      {
        field: "responsavelLiberacao ",
        headerName: "Responsável pela liberação",
        type: "string",
        tipo: "java.lang.String",
        grid: true,
        joinType: "JOIN",
        flex: 1,
        hide: false,
        tipoFiltro: "CONTEM",
        aplicarFiltro: true,
        sequenciaOrdenacao: 0,
        ordenacaoAscendente: true,
        opcoesEnum: "",
        disableColumnMenu: true,
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <DataGrid
        getRowId={(row) => row.codigo}
        density={dense ? "compact" : "standard"}
        disableSelectionOnClick
        rows={ []}
        paginationMode="server"
        filterMode="server"
        columns={columns}
        pagination
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

I have another equal component and it renders the columns on the screen, I couldn't find a solution. I think it might be something related to the route I'm calling this component maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this prop in DataGrid

```
autoHeight={true}
```

or wrap it with `Box` and set manual height

Reference: [MUI datagrid Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cevk2k?file=/demo.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Grid is displayed but you have to give it minimum height or auto height

Here is sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-paper-yqj9qp?file=/src/App.js